# character input error in my C program?

Tags: c, input, char

I am new to C programming, I have made a simple calculator program in C.

The program runs but doesn't work, it works till value for `b` is entered after then when character input comes it *doesn't ask* for the input. I don't know why this is happening but is there any fix?

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a,b;
    char op;
    printf("enter a: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("enter b: ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("enter operation: ");
    scanf("%c",&op);
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("\n%.2f %c %.2f = %.2f",a,op,b,a+b);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("\n%.2f %c %.2f = %.2f",a,op,b,a-b);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("\n%.2f %c %.2f = %.2f",a,op,b,a*b);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("\n%.2f %c %.2f = %.2f",a,op,b,a/b);
            break;
        default:
            printf("invallid input!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program seems to be absolutely correct but still there is something there I am missing. Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a **space** before your enter operation's `scanf()` function's *character format specifier* and your program will work fine:

```
scanf( " %c" , &op );
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `scanf()`, it will leave behind a `\n` character in the input  buffer. The next `scanf()` will keep this newline and store it.  You need to either add a space to `scanf()`:

```
scanf(" %c", &op); /* to skip any number of white space characters */
```

Or consume the character instead with `getchar()`. The function `getchar()` returns `int` and `EOF` on error It can be used this way:

```
int op = getchar()
```

Which stores the character found in `op`. You could also just add `getchar()` after your `scanf()` calls, which will consume the leftover `\n` character.

**Note:** It is good practice to check result of `scanf()`. You should write instead:

```
if (scanf(" %c", &op) != 1) {
    /* oops, non character found. Handle error */
```